Proof of divergence of a simple sequence
Suppose $b_n$ is a strictly decreasing sequence which tends to $-\infty$, with $b_0 = 0$.
I am trying to find the limit of the sequence $E_n$ defined recursively as
$$E_0 = 0,$$
$$E_n = \max_{i \in \{ 0,...,n-1 \}}(E_i + b_{n-i}).$$
Ideally, and I believe that in general, $E_n$ diverges to $-\infty$.
I have already proved by induction that, for $\delta_n = \min_{i \in \{ 1,...,n\}}|b_i - b_{i-1}|$, then $E_n \leq -n\delta_n $, but for example if $b_n = -\sum_{i=1}^n\frac1i$, then the estimate does not help. However, for this choice of $b_n$, I have manually computed the first 10 values of $E_n$ and they are equal to $b_n$, and so if this pattern continues, $E_n$ diverges to $-\infty$. Even for an example of $b_n$ which decreases even slower, $b_n = -\ln(\ln(n+e))$, it still seems to diverge to $-\infty$, albeit extremely slowly. However I am unable to find any further arguments that might prove whether this is always the case.
Any help would be appreciated.

I don't understand—why isn't it the case that $E_n = b_{n-1}$ for all $n\ge1$?

This is a trivial comment: define $c_n = -b_n$ and $F_n = -E_n$ so that $c_n$ is positive and increasing to $\infty$, and $F_n = \min_{i\in{0,\ldots,n-1}} F_i + c_{n-i}$. The problem then is to prove or disprove that $F_n$ is increasing to $\infty$. This way everything is positive, which to me is simpler to think about.

@GregMartin $E_1=b_1$, which is already inconsistent with what you wrote. Also, $E_2 = \max(b_2,2b_1)$, and I don't see why this has to be $b_1$.

For the record, the definition was changed after these comments were written.

The result is true and we will prove it by contradiction. First we notice that we can also write  $$E_n=\max_{j=1,..n}(E_{n-j}+b_j)$$
Assume there is a fixed $A<0$ and a subsequence $E_{n_k} \ge A$ and consider $I$ the infinite set of all $n$ st $E_n \ge A$, $J$ the finite set of all $k$ st $b_k \ge A$ and $N_J$ the largest index in $J$
Also for every $n$ let's denote by $1 \le m_n \le n$ the (smallest if there is more than one) index for which $E_n=b_{m_n}+E_{n-m_n}$. Then for every $n \in I$  we have $m_n \in J, n-m_n \in I$ since $b_n, E_n<0, n \ge 1$.
Pick a large $K>0$ integral st $Kb_1<A$ and pick a large $N \in I$ (infinite) st $N-KN_J>0$ and then we have $$E_N=b_{m_N}+E_{N-m_N}=b_{m_N}+E_{N_1}$$ with $N_1=N-m_N >(K-1)N_J, N_1 \in I$ since $m_N \in J$ so $m_N \le N_J$ while $N >KN_J$
Repeat for $E_{N_1}$ and get $m_{N_1} \in J, N_2=N_1-m_{N_1}>(K-2)N_J, N_2 \in I$ st $$E_{N_1}=b_{m_{N_1}}+E_{N_2}$$ and so on until we get $N_K>0, m_{N_{K-1}}\in J, N_K \in I$ and $$E_{N_{K-1}}=b_{m_{N_{K-1}}}+E_{N_K}$$
Putting it together we get $$E_N=b_{m_N}+b_{m_{N_1}}+..b_{m_{N_{K-1}}}+E_{N_K}\le Kb_1+E_{N_K}<A$$ and that is a contradiction so we are done!

Amazing. May I ask where the estimate for $N_i$ comes in? Otherwise this is exactly what I needed, thank you very much. Was it inspiration or had you seen something similar?

The crucial point about $N_i$ is that they are positive so indeed we have a legitimate $E$ there that we can keep pushing down with an extra $b$ - doing that enough times gives enough $b$'s to go below any constant since $b_1<0$ and all the rest are smaller- for this to work from a large but fixed original height $N$ we need an uniform bound on the index size of the $b$'s and here the fact that the $b$'s go to minus infinity is crucial - note that we just use that and the fact that all are negative from $b_1$; the decreasing is unnecessary since instead of $b_1$ we can use $\min b_k=b<0, k>0$

As for the idea, I think it is the natural one since I thought how one would go to construct a counterexample and realized that if we keep infinitely many $E$ above some $A$ we can use only finitely many $b$ in their definition (since the $b$ go eventually below any such $A$ while the $E$ are negative) so those have an uniform bounded index but then this means that we have to add arbitrarily many as we go to higher and higher $E_N$ so we cannot actually stay above any constant

Beautiful. Thank you.

happy to be of help
